# Android - Order Firebase Array by timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android chat application in which I need to order the conversation details by the timestamp. My firebase data structure is mentioned below .

[image]

I have tried the following approaches.

**Approach A**

***Defining DatabaseReference***

```
DatabaseReference conversationReference = mFirebaseDatabaseReference
                 .child(USERS).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(CONV_DETAILS).orderByChild("last_time_stamp").getRef();
```

***Defining  FirebaseRecycler Adapter***

```
 mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ConversationDetails,
                    ConversationsViewHolder>(
                    ConversationDetails.class,
                    R.layout.conversation_list_item,
                    ConversationsViewHolder.class, conversationReference) {


                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ConversationsViewHolder viewHolder,
                                                  final ConversationDetails conversationDetails, int position) {
}
};
```

**Approach B:**

***Prefixing a minus symbol before field name***

```
conversationReference = mFirebaseDatabaseReference
                .child(USERS).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(CONV_DETAILS).orderByChild("-last_time_stamp").getRef();
```

Both scenarios do not work and displaying only in the order of array stored in the firebase database.But, I need to display the conversation details with the higher value of `last_time_stamp` as first.

Please anyone help me finding the solution.

Comment: is the timestamp generated with ServerValue upon creation of the entry ?

Comment: Approach B is not usable you can't change the key. Approach A should be working. Remove the get Ref and use Query.

Comment: @gbaccetta Yes,  SeverValue.TIMESTAMP value was inserted

Comment: @drulabs . Let me try this and revert you.

Comment: @RakeshL ok. Just FYI. Query is the superclass for Database reference, so you can attach listeners normally like you do with Database references.

Comment: @drulabs. Thanks .It is working but not as expected. I need recent timestamp at the top. but it displays at bottom.

Comment: than just use a reverseLayout = true in your RecyclerView, ListView. That should work. Yiou can also add a stackFromEnd if needed

Comment: solution by @gbaccetta is correct. But it will mess up in pagination.

Comment: can you post your layout? Are you using LinearLayoutManager or another layout manager?

Comment: more depth in sorting items in FBrecycler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249524/sorting-items-position-using-firebaserecycleradapter/42319463#42319463

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Query to query the data and perform `orderByValue()`. This always gives data in ascending order. so you can either reverse the data, or flip the `Recycler` view to show latest chat.

Do not forget to add limit. Use limit to get that last items from the ascending ordered list.

```
Query chatQuery = conversationReference.orderByChild("last_time_stamp"). limitToLast(20);
```

This will give you 20 latest chats in ascending order timestamp. Now flip this list and use it.

Or you can always set `reverseLayout` to `true` in your recycler view.
Also add `setStackFromEnd` to `true`.

Comment: If I set the reverse layout to true , it is working but the list is moved to bottom and top of the list is empty

Comment: set StackFromBottom = false and that should be fixed

Comment: I made that too,but no break through :-(

Comment: It was working if I set as true for both like     mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); .. Thanks for your precious help @drulabs and gbaccetta . Please edit you answer so that it will help to others too.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this inside the firebase recycler adapter -

```
@Override
        public ModelClass getItem(int position) {
            return super.getItem(getItemCount() - 1 - position);
        }
```