# Firebase UI: How to add new message to the top of recycleView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Recycle Adapter to display my messages. I want to display newly received message on top of the recycle view. 
E.g newly sent/received message by Jfi.. should be on top.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my db structure.

[image: db structure]

Code:

```
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = rootRef.child("messages").child(messageSenderId).child(messageReceiverId);


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .build();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the messages into Firebase with a timestamp, then when you retrieve all the data of the message, compare it to the rest of the messages and sort it by the date, and they will display at the top the newest ones, or just invert the `RecyclerView` and you will see the latest messages at the top of the `RecyclerView`

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

**EDIT**

You can compare the values of each message and sort them by the timestamp you get from Firebase

```
 public class timeStampSort implements Comparator<YourModel> {

        @Override
        public int compare(YourModel o1, YourModel o2) {
            return Long.compare(o2.getTimestamp(), o1.getTimestamp());

        }

    }
```

and then before calling `mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter....` do this

```
Collections.sort(yourArray, new timeStampSort());
```

That should order your messages with the timestamp from each one without having to invert the `RecyclerView`

The above sort can be done if you already made another orderByChild in your query and you can't do more than once.

But, as Frank suggests, it's much more efficient to do it with `orderByChild`, so you can only do this

```
Query query = rootRef.child("messages").child(messageSenderId).child(messageReceiverId).orderByChild("timestamp");
```

Comment: I have tried linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); but it didn't work. timestamp sounds good :)

Comment: yes, pushing the messages with a timestamp can then be retrieved and ordered with a collection.sort , use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976747/android-order-firebase-array-by-timestamp  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Comment: Great. Let me check.

Comment: I have used ServerValue.TIMESTAMP and its working great. But I am still unable to order by timestamp. Kindly let me know what I am missing.
DB: 
https://imgur.com/a/zzjn7dw

Code: 
https://imgur.com/a/Ta9dBn4

Comment: Firebase Database queries are always ascending. So if you want the newest node to be on top, you'll want to store for example an inverted timestamp and order on that. E.g. `nodeRef.child("invertedTimestamp").setValue(0 - System.currentTimeMillis())` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse. Luckily Android makes it easy to do the inversion in the UI, which I completely forgot about, but luckily Gastón didn't. ;-) For more on these, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebaseui%5D+reverse

Comment: To order the results from your query by timestamp: `Query query = rootRef.child("messages").child(messageSenderId).child(messageReceiverId).orderByChild("timestamp");`

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, I'm just at the same problem with another app that I have, this for sure will help !  :) , I just added the Collection sort since in my use case I queried before with orderByChild and cant use it again, but it is always better to use it with the timestamp, will include this in the answer as well