# Load Firestore documents descending order by time from bottom to top

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am paginating data into a tableview for a messaging app. This is my query function and then I handle the response, data, and error:

```
func getMessages(userId: String, scrolled: Bool) {
        var query: Query!
        if scrolled {
            guard let lastDocument = lastDocument else { return }
            query = db.collection("Customer_Data").document(userId).collection("Contact_Messages").order(by: "sent", descending: true).limit(to: 10).start(afterDocument: lastDocument)
        } else {
            lastDocument = nil
            query = db.collection("Customer_Data").document(userId).collection("Contact_Messages").order(by: "sent", descending: true).limit(to: 10)
        }
        handleResponse(query: query)
    }

func handleResponse(query: Query) {
        query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.messageReceived?(nil, error.localizedDescription, .error)
            } else if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                self.messageReceived?(nil, nil, .end)
            } else if !querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                let polledMessages = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { querySnapshot -> Message? in
                    return try? querySnapshot.data(as: Message.self)
                }
                guard let availableMessages = polledMessages else { return }
                var messageArray = [Message]()
                messageArray.append(contentsOf: availableMessages)
                self.lastDocument = querySnapshot!.documents.last
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: {
                    self.messageReceived?(messageArray, nil, .success)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Now here, I add the next set of data to the top of the array:

```
func handleResponse(query: Query) {
        query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.messageReceived?(nil, error.localizedDescription, .error)
            } else if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                self.messageReceived?(nil, nil, .end)
            } else if !querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                let polledMessages = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { querySnapshot -> Message? in
                    return try? querySnapshot.data(as: Message.self)
                }
                guard let availableMessages = polledMessages else { return }
                var messageArray = [Message]()
                messageArray.append(contentsOf: availableMessages)
                self.lastDocument = querySnapshot!.documents.last
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: {
                    self.messageReceived?(messageArray, nil, .success)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that instead of seeing messages like this:

the first batch (newest first as the query is descending order of timestamp mentioned above):
20 Oct
25 Oct
28 Oct
31 Oct

second batch:
06 Oct
07 Oct
15 Oct
18 Oct

Once arranged in the array, I should get them all arranged nearly in descending order the further up I scroll just like Whatsapp, FB Messenger etc.

I am seeing this:

first batch (seems fine)
20 Oct
25 Oct
28 Oct
31 Oct

the second batch (in the reverse order)
18 Oct
15 Oct
07 Oct
06 Oct

Any idea why this is happening?

For reference, this is where I trigger the pagination:

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let off = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let off1 = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if off < off1 + scrollView.frame.height * leadingScreensForBatching, let userId = userId {
        messageViewModel.getMessages(userId: userId, scrolled: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Order Firebase Array by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976747/android-order-firebase-array-by-timestamp)

Comment: No, it didn't. I ended up reversing the objects in the array as soon as I queried them from the API.